# Django ecommerce: Reverse for 'cart_add' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/add/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

This is my first ecommerce web-site with django and it's a little tough to wrap my head around all the routing and cart function, and I fixed lots of stuff, but I just can't fix this error. I tried doing some stuff in urls but it just didn't work out.

onlineshop/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('onlineshop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, related_name='product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('onlineshop:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

onlineshop/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import *
from cart.forms import CartAddProductForm

def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        'category': category,
        'products': products,
    }
    return render(request, 'onlineshop/product/list.html', context)


def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    context = {
        'product': product,
        'cart_product_form':cart_product_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'onlineshop/product/detail.html')
```

onlineshop/base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %}My Shop{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <a href="/" class="logo">My Shop</a>
    </div>
    <div id="subheader">
      <div class="cart">
        Your cart is empty
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      {% block content %}
      
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

onlineshop/detail.html:

```
{% extends "onlineshop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
  {{ product.title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="product-detail">
    <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{%static 'img/no_image.png' %}{% endif %}">
    <h1>
      {{ product.name}}
    </h1>
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ product.category.get_absolute_url }}">
        {{ product.category }}
      </a>
    </h2>
    <p class="price">
      {{ product.price }}GEL
    </p>
    <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" method="post">
      {{ cart_product_form }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
    </form>

  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

onlineshop/views.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'onlineshop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list,
         name='product_list_by_category'),

    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail')
]
```

cart/cart.py:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from onlineshop.models import Product

class Cart(object):

    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.sessions.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
            if not cart:
                cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
            self.cart = cart

    def add(self, product, quantity=1, override_quantity=False):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id]={'quantity':0, 'price':str(product.price),}

        if override_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()


    def remove(self, product):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def __iter__(self):
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        cart = self.cart.copy()
        for product in products:
            cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item


    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())



    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price'] * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values()))


    def clear(self):
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.save()
```

cart/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from onlineshop.models import *
from .cart import Cart
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from .forms import *


@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CardAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        card.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], override_quantity=cd['override'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    context = {
        'cart':cart,
    }
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', context)
```

cart/forms.py

```
from django import forms

PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i,str(i)) for i in range(1,21)]
class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES, coerce=int)
    override = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

cart/detail.html:

```
{% extends onlineshop/base.html %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
  Shopping Cart
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
<table class="cart">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Image
      </th>
      <th>
        Product
      </th>
      <th>
        Quantity
      </th>
      <th>
        Product
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for item in cart %}
    {% with product = item.product %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="{{product.get_absolute_url}}">
          <img src = "{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static 'img/no_image.png' %}"{% endif %}>

        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ product.name }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ item.quantity }}
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_remove' product.id %}" method="post">
          <input type="submit" value="Remove" />
          {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="num">
        {{ item.price }}GEL
      </td>
      <td class="num">
        {{ item.total_price }}GEL
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        Total
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">

      </td>
      <td class="num">
        {{ cart.get_total_price }}GEL
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p class="text-right">
  <a href="{% url 'onlineshop:product_list' %}" class="buttonlight">Continue Shopping</a>
  <a href="#" class="button">Checkout</a>
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

cart/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'cart'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    path('add/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_add, name='cart_add'),
    path('remove/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove')
]
```

Comment: you don't pass any `product` to `detail.html`: `context = {'cart':cart,}`

Comment: @IvanStarostin I added **product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product)** and product in context, but it doesn't work

Comment: Update your question with modified code and actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I didn't have 'context' mentioned in `return render()` in **onlineshop/views.py**

Answer (score 0):

Your routing logic is fine, i think your only mistake is in the use of quotes in the template `onlineshop/detail.html`

You have:

```html
<form action="{% url "cart:cart_add" product.id %}" method="post">
```

And must to be:

```html
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" method="post">
```

This problem it is caused because you have nested quotes, you need to change the nested double quotes to single quotes.

The same problem is present in the same file `onlineshop/detail.html` line:

```html
<img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{%static "img/no_image.png"%}{% endif %}">
```

and in the template `cart/detail.html`, lines:

```html
<img src = "{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}"{% endif %}>
```

```html
<form action="{% url "cart:cart_remove" product.id %}" method="post">
```

```html
<a href="{% url "onlineshop:product_list" %}" class="buttonlight">Continue Shopping</a>
```

Comment: @Myrodis I believe I have added the origin of your new error in the updated response, if the error persists, check if it is not another error

Comment: I replaced the double quotes everywhere, but I keep getting the same error.